# vim: move to pattern without changing current pattern

Tags: vim

While editing huge files, I need to move around based on pattern search (despite me using ctags, cscope, Lid) but I don't want to disturb the current highlight search while doing so.

The reason being the pattern I am going to use is for extremely short period of time and I would have to manually restore the last pattern back again.

Let me explain by example. If I have a file like following:

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2
  3 int main(int argc, char **argc)
  4 {
  5         printf("Hello World")
  6         foo();
  7         return 0;
  8 }
  9
 10 void foo(void)
 11 {
 12         printf("Just another function with no declaration yet\n");
 13 }
```

lets say cursor is at line 5. `printf("Hello World")` and my current search pattern is printf.

Now I want to do add the prototype for the function foo(). I would have to do following:

1. Search upwards for #include to get the last instance of #include in the file
2. Add the prototype for foo in the next line
3. Restore the last search pattern i.e. printf

What I want is when I had moved to line 1 by searching for #include, it should just move to the occurrence without changing the current pattern.

Is it possible to acheive this in vim easily?

**TLDR**
I want to move/jump within a file, based on pattern without changing the current pattern so that the next time I do n or N the old pattern still works without having to restore it by doing `/` then `uparrow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these custom mappings to search upward and downward without "polluting" the search history (used by `nN`) or removing the highlight from the preceding "normal" search:

```
nnoremap ,/ :<C-u>call search(input("/"))<CR>
nnoremap ,? :<C-u>call search(input("?"),"b")<CR>
```

Overriding the normal `/` and `?` doesn't sound to me as a viable idea.